# External hard drive gets disconnected while writing files to it

Tags: hard-drive, raid, external-hdd, luks, cryptsetup

**Ubuntu 17.10**

I have a HW-RAID enclosure with two drives in RAID 1.
The drive is formatted and encrypted LUKS/EXT4.
The drive works perfectly when mounted or dismounted or when a few small files are written.
(Note that I have several different drives from different manufacturers as well as several different enclosures from different manufacturers, all combinations of drive/enclosure produce this outcome.)

Now when I start copying (`cp -ivpr source destination`) large amounts of data (20GB or more) to the drive the following happens:

After some time (sometimes 2 minutes, sometimes 20 or more)

- the `cp` process stops showing output in terminal and just freezes there at the last file
- a minute or so later the drive gets (probably) disconnected, audio signal for removed hardware
- the drive shuts down altogether, unplugging and replugging won't do anything, also the leds for read/write are off (but power led is still on)
- `gnome-disk-utility` still shows the drive as plugged in but not as mounted, this state will also not change by unplugging and replugging
- the `cp` process won't react to `CTRL+C` or `kill` or `kill -9` or `kill -f` or any other `kill`
- I therefore unplug the drive and restart the system
- at shut down the following errors are displayed and the shut down process stops there and I have to do a hard reset

Errors at shut down

```
[ 7638.407548] wlp61s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
[ 7638.407938] wlp61s0: failed to remove key (2, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
```

This is `dmesg -T -w` right after #3 the drive shuts down altogether

```
[Son Mär 25 22:08:28 2018] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 17 42 0c ff 00 04 00 00
[Son Mär 25 22:08:28 2018] scsi host1: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
[Son Mär 25 22:08:33 2018] usb 4-1.2: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[Son Mär 25 22:08:39 2018] usb 4-1.2: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[Son Mär 25 22:08:45 2018] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Son Mär 25 22:08:50 2018] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Son Mär 25 22:08:50 2018] usb 4-1.2: device not accepting address 3, error -62
[Son Mär 25 22:08:56 2018] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Son Mär 25 22:09:01 2018] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Son Mär 25 22:09:01 2018] usb 4-1.2: device not accepting address 3, error -62
[Son Mär 25 22:09:07 2018] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Son Mär 25 22:09:12 2018] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Son Mär 25 22:09:12 2018] usb 4-1.2: device not accepting address 3, error -62
[Son Mär 25 22:09:18 2018] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Son Mär 25 22:09:23 2018] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Son Mär 25 22:09:23 2018] usb 4-1.2: device not accepting address 3, error -62
[Son Mär 25 22:09:23 2018] scsi host1: uas_post_reset: alloc streams error -19 after reset
[Son Mär 25 22:09:23 2018] usb 4-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[Son Mär 25 22:09:23 2018] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] INFO: task dmcrypt_write:3517 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]       Not tainted 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] dmcrypt_write   D    0  3517      2 0x80000000
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] Call Trace:
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __schedule+0x291/0x8a0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  io_schedule+0x16/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  get_request+0x288/0x7c0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  blk_queue_bio+0x118/0x400
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  generic_make_request+0x12a/0x310
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  dmcrypt_write+0x230/0x260 [dm_crypt]
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? dmcrypt_write+0x230/0x260 [dm_crypt]
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? wake_up_q+0x80/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  kthread+0x128/0x140
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? crypt_iv_lmk_gen+0xa0/0xa0 [dm_crypt]
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? kthread+0x128/0x140
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? crypt_iv_lmk_gen+0xa0/0xa0 [dm_crypt]
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x70/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x130
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? SyS_exit_group+0x14/0x20
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] INFO: task jbd2/dm-0-8:3575 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]       Not tainted 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] jbd2/dm-0-8     D    0  3575      2 0x80000000
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] Call Trace:
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __schedule+0x291/0x8a0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? __update_load_avg_se.isra.37+0x155/0x160
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  jbd2_journal_commit_transaction+0x244/0x16d0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? lock_timer_base+0x75/0x90
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  kjournald2+0xd2/0x280
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? kjournald2+0xd2/0x280
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  kthread+0x128/0x140
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? commit_timeout+0x10/0x10
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x70/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? do_syscall_64+0x113/0x130
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] INFO: task ext4lazyinit:3577 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]       Not tainted 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] ext4lazyinit    D    0  3577      2 0x80000000
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] Call Trace:
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __schedule+0x291/0x8a0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  schedule_timeout+0x1f4/0x360
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  io_schedule_timeout+0x1e/0x50
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? io_schedule_timeout+0x1e/0x50
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  wait_for_completion_io+0xba/0x140
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? wake_up_q+0x80/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  submit_bio_wait+0x68/0x90
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  blkdev_issue_zeroout+0x80/0xc0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x2a/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ext4_init_inode_table+0x187/0x37b
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? ext4_init_inode_table+0x187/0x37b
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ext4_lazyinit_thread+0x2a3/0x3b0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  kthread+0x128/0x140
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? ext4_clear_request_list+0x70/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x70/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] INFO: task kworker/u16:5:3331 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]       Not tainted 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] kworker/u16:5   D    0  3331      2 0x80000000
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] Workqueue: writeback wb_workfn (flush-253:0)
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] Call Trace:
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __schedule+0x291/0x8a0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? bit_wait+0x60/0x60
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  io_schedule+0x16/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  bit_wait_io+0x11/0x60
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __wait_on_bit_lock+0x5d/0xc0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? pagecache_get_page+0x77/0x210
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  out_of_line_wait_on_bit_lock+0x90/0xb0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? bit_waitqueue+0x40/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __lock_buffer+0x32/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  do_get_write_access+0x27d/0x440
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x51/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x5a/0xb0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ext4_reserve_inode_write+0x93/0xb0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? __ext4_ext_dirty+0x6c/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x53/0x1d0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? __ext4_handle_dirty_metadata+0x87/0x1c0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __ext4_ext_dirty+0x6c/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ext4_ext_insert_extent+0x788/0x1330
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? __kmalloc+0x1c7/0x200
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? ext4_find_extent+0x243/0x2b0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ext4_ext_map_blocks+0x1d3/0xec0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ext4_map_blocks+0x3b2/0x5d0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? ext4_writepages+0x5d5/0xf40
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ext4_writepages+0x87c/0xf40
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  do_writepages+0x4b/0xe0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x1d0/0x1d0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? do_writepages+0x4b/0xe0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? ext4_write_inode+0x37/0x140
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __writeback_single_inode+0x45/0x330
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? __writeback_single_inode+0x45/0x330
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  writeback_sb_inodes+0x1e4/0x550
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __writeback_inodes_wb+0x67/0xb0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  wb_writeback+0x271/0x300
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  wb_workfn+0x171/0x380
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? wb_workfn+0x171/0x380
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  process_one_work+0x1ec/0x410
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  worker_thread+0x32/0x410
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  kthread+0x128/0x140
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x70/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] INFO: task cp:18614 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]       Not tainted 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] cp              D    0 18614   2993 0x00000000
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] Call Trace:
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __schedule+0x291/0x8a0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? bit_wait+0x60/0x60
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  io_schedule+0x16/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  bit_wait_io+0x11/0x60
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __wait_on_bit+0x4c/0x90
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? ext4_getblk+0xa9/0x190
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  out_of_line_wait_on_bit+0x90/0xb0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? bit_waitqueue+0x40/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __wait_on_buffer+0x32/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ext4_find_entry+0x1fc/0x4f0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? kmem_cache_alloc+0x153/0x1a0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ? __d_alloc+0x27/0x1d0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  ext4_lookup+0xc5/0x260
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  __lookup_hash+0x6a/0xa0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  filename_create+0x91/0x160
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  SyS_mkdir+0x56/0x110
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018]  entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x24/0xab
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] RIP: 0033:0x7f6bd72daca7
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] RSP: 002b:00007ffd22313708 EFLAGS: 00000206 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000053
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000001000 RCX: 00007f6bd72daca7
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] RDX: 0000000002100350 RSI: 00000000000001c0 RDI: 0000556319ac62b0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] RBP: 00007ffd22312e80 R08: 00007ffd22313c50 R09: 0000000000000000
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] R10: 0000556319ac2260 R11: 0000000000000206 R12: 00007ffd22312fc0
[Son Mär 25 22:10:06 2018] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000556319ac6950 R15: 00007ffd22313300
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] INFO: task GUsbEventThread:1945 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]       Not tainted 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] GUsbEventThread D    0  1945      1 0x00000100
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] Call Trace:
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  __schedule+0x291/0x8a0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? compat_poll_select_copy_remaining+0x120/0x120
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xe/0x10
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  __mutex_lock.isra.2+0x18c/0x4d0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  mutex_lock+0x2f/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  usbdev_do_ioctl+0x60/0x1170
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? __seccomp_filter+0x46/0x390
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? compat_poll_select_copy_remaining+0x120/0x120
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  usbdev_ioctl+0xe/0x20
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  do_vfs_ioctl+0xa8/0x630
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? __secure_computing+0x3f/0x100
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? syscall_trace_enter+0xda/0x2d0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  do_syscall_64+0x67/0x130
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  entry_SYSCALL64_slow_path+0x25/0x25
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] RIP: 0033:0x7f3937c03ef7
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] RSP: 002b:00007f392d903b08 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000011 RCX: 00007f3937c03ef7
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] RDX: 00007f392d903b30 RSI: 000000004008550d RDI: 0000000000000027
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000027 R09: 000000000000ea60
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] R10: 00007f3920000e4c R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007f3920000e00
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] R13: 00007f3920001e20 R14: 00005599e3a6e000 R15: 00005599e3a6e048
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] INFO: task scsi_eh_1:3394 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]       Not tainted 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] scsi_eh_1       D    0  3394      2 0x80000000
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] Call Trace:
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  __schedule+0x291/0x8a0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  io_schedule+0x16/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  get_request+0x288/0x7c0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  blk_get_request+0x9d/0x110
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  scsi_execute+0x40/0x250
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  sd_sync_cache+0xa3/0x180
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  sd_shutdown+0x6e/0x100
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  sd_remove+0x69/0xd0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  device_release_driver_internal+0x15b/0x210
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  device_release_driver+0x12/0x20
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  bus_remove_device+0xec/0x160
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  device_del+0x1d9/0x350
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? kobject_put+0x94/0x1a0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  __scsi_remove_device+0xff/0x130
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  scsi_forget_host+0x25/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  scsi_remove_host+0x77/0x110
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  uas_disconnect+0x85/0xa0 [uas]
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  usb_unbind_interface+0x77/0x290
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  device_release_driver_internal+0x15b/0x210
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  device_release_driver+0x12/0x20
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  usb_driver_release_interface+0x78/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  usb_forced_unbind_intf+0x2a/0x50
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  unbind_marked_interfaces.isra.15+0x4e/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  usb_unbind_and_rebind_marked_interfaces+0x19/0x30
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  usb_reset_device+0x1ad/0x270
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  uas_eh_bus_reset_handler+0xb0/0x180 [uas]
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  scsi_try_bus_reset+0x48/0x100
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  scsi_eh_ready_devs+0x75d/0xbf0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? scsi_try_target_reset+0x90/0x90
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  scsi_error_handler+0x4c3/0x5b0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  kthread+0x128/0x140
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? scsi_eh_get_sense+0x200/0x200
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x70/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] INFO: task dmcrypt_write:3517 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]       Not tainted 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] dmcrypt_write   D    0  3517      2 0x80000000
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] Call Trace:
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  __schedule+0x291/0x8a0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  io_schedule+0x16/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  get_request+0x288/0x7c0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  blk_queue_bio+0x118/0x400
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  generic_make_request+0x12a/0x310
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  dmcrypt_write+0x230/0x260 [dm_crypt]
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? dmcrypt_write+0x230/0x260 [dm_crypt]
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? wake_up_q+0x80/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  kthread+0x128/0x140
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? crypt_iv_lmk_gen+0xa0/0xa0 [dm_crypt]
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? kthread+0x128/0x140
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? crypt_iv_lmk_gen+0xa0/0xa0 [dm_crypt]
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x70/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x130
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? SyS_exit_group+0x14/0x20
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] INFO: task jbd2/dm-0-8:3575 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]       Not tainted 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] jbd2/dm-0-8     D    0  3575      2 0x80000000
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] Call Trace:
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  __schedule+0x291/0x8a0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? __update_load_avg_se.isra.37+0x155/0x160
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  jbd2_journal_commit_transaction+0x244/0x16d0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? lock_timer_base+0x75/0x90
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  kjournald2+0xd2/0x280
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? kjournald2+0xd2/0x280
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  kthread+0x128/0x140
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? commit_timeout+0x10/0x10
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x70/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? do_syscall_64+0x113/0x130
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] INFO: task ext4lazyinit:3577 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]       Not tainted 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] ext4lazyinit    D    0  3577      2 0x80000000
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018] Call Trace:
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  __schedule+0x291/0x8a0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  schedule_timeout+0x1f4/0x360
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  io_schedule_timeout+0x1e/0x50
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? io_schedule_timeout+0x1e/0x50
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  wait_for_completion_io+0xba/0x140
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? wake_up_q+0x80/0x80
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  submit_bio_wait+0x68/0x90
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  blkdev_issue_zeroout+0x80/0xc0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x2a/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ext4_init_inode_table+0x187/0x37b
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? ext4_init_inode_table+0x187/0x37b
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ext4_lazyinit_thread+0x2a3/0x3b0
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  kthread+0x128/0x140
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? ext4_clear_request_list+0x70/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x70/0x70
[Son Mär 25 22:12:07 2018]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You may have a power issue. Do you have access to a **POWERED** USB hub that you can plug in, between the USB port and the RAID enclosure(s)? Or optionally, do your RAID enclosures allow the use of an external power supply?

Comment: @heynnema Those enclosures all can be powered externally, and I power them with wall chargers from mains. I too think that it is a power issue but that's not it. Also I started testing other things like watching a movie from such a drive in a loop for (many) hours, or copying large amounts not by `cp` but by `nautilus gui` which all work fine. So i am guessing it has to do something with `cp` and/or the usb ports not beeing powered after a while when `cp` is working.